# Typo in a bounty reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

[screenshot http://phpcode.eu/images/1316874146.png](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316874146.png)

See above. The word "additional" is missing the second `i`.

Comment: @genesis: This is a rather odd circle `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I didn't edit it, my modified US did

Comment: For what it's worth, [this is even misspelled on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/). At least they're consistent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Waffles made a typo and we didn't catch it.. fixed in source control.

Comment: Install a spell-checking hook in your source control.